# How use theme's function into plugin's file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a simple plugin of wordpress, and trying to use theme's function into plugin's file, but it is saying "Call to undefined function", while that function exists in themes.php of current active theme.that function is in use in theme's files but can't accessible in plugin's file, can anyone guide what to do?
while I have to attach plugin with theme as mandatory plugin.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are loaded before the theme so the function hasn't been defined at the time you're calling it. Execute your code on a hook such as `init` instead.

E.g.

```
function wpse_my_plugin_init() {
    myPreviouslyUndefinedThemeFunction();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_my_plugin_init' );
```

See here for a list of hook options: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

The earliest opportunity you have to call this code would be `after_setup_theme`.

On another note I'd suggest rethinking this approach. A plugin should be an independent module; it shouldn't be tied to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach/design is serious flawed. Plugin functionality should never rely on theme functionality. As already pointed out by @NathanDawson, plugins get loaded first, then child theme functions then parent theme functions, so your approach will never work as indented or without a lot of unnecessary bloated code

Plugins are meant to extend **site** functionality, and not **theme** functionality. I think this is where your idea is seriously flawed, and most probably due to a lack of knowledge on who should do what and when

As I have stated, plugins should give functionality to the site. Functionalities like favicons, custom post types, custom taxonomies, shortcodes, widgets, related posts and rewrite rules **should** be in a plugin. This gives functionality to your site, which simply mean, when you change the theme, these functionalities won't change or they won't be affected. Also, if the plugin is removed, it doesn't change the way how the theme looks and operate.

Theme specific functions are functions that gives functionality to the theme itself. Without these functions, the theme looses functionality or its looks. It simply means thant the theme changes. These functions includes functions to enqueue your stylesheets and scripts, theme suppport functions, sidebars, custom headers and backgrounds and registering image sizes.

If you are going to make a plugin rely on theme code, you should be looking to create a child theme, as child themes are meant to extend the main theme. Child themes inherit all functionalities from the parent theme, and can extend, modify or add new functionality to the parent theme.

To conclude, by making a plugin rely on theme code, you are making your site very vulnerable to breakage. If you change your theme, you will break your site as you will break your plugin. This is not how plugins and themes were made to interact. By creating a child theme instead, you void that risk as child themes **cannot** be activated without the parent theme being in the theme's folder and neither can any two themes be activated at the same time.